Is either $\mathsf{BPP}$ or $\mathsf{NP}$ low for the other? And $\mathsf{PP}$ vs. $\mathsf{NP}$?
Is it an open question whether $\mathsf{BPP}$ is low for $\mathsf{NP}$?
Is it an open question whether $\mathsf{NP}$ is low for $\mathsf{BPP}$?
If both are open questions, what do you think is more likely to be true?
One thing I know is that, under the widely believed assumption $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{BPP}$, $\mathsf{BPP}$ is low for $\mathsf{NP}$ since $\mathsf{P}$ is low for $\mathsf{NP}$. Also, assuming $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{BPP}$ and $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$, $\mathsf{NP}$ is not low for $\mathsf{BPP}$ since otherwise $\mathsf{NP}$ is low for $\mathsf{P}$.
What if I replace $\mathsf{BPP}$ with $\mathsf{PP}$ in my question? Then I would expect $\mathsf{PP}$ is not low for $\mathsf{NP}$ since $\mathsf{PH} \subseteq \mathsf{NP}^\mathsf{PP}$ and $\mathsf{PH}$ is unlikely to collapse. I don't know what to say about whether $\mathsf{NP}$ is low for $\mathsf{PP}$ though.

It's even open whether either containment holds between NP and BPP. You answer the question "what do you think is more likely to be true" yourself (or at least "what's mostly likely to be true according to the lore").
